# Dart: create instance from a class (difference)

Tags: class, dart, variables, instance, instance-variables

Based on that simple class:

```
class User { String? name; int? id; }
```

I'm not sure what is the difference between:

**var user = User();**


or:

**User user = User();**

If someone can shed some light on this I'll be more than happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no practical difference in this case. When you use the `var` keyword, the type will be inferred by the compiler, whereas declaring it as `User` is simply a way to explicitly define the type.

There are some cases where it would make some difference though, such as when instantiating a generic type, like `List`.

If you type:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
```

Then `list` will have a type of `List<int>`. But you might have wanted a list of `double`s. In that case, you could write:

```
List<double> list = [1, 2, 3];
```

And you would be assured that `list` would have the type you want (though of course in this case you could also simply write `var list = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`).

It's also helpful when instantiating an empty list, since in that case there are no values in the list from which the compiler can infer the type.

Comment: You also can do `var list = <double>[1, 2, 3];` and `var emptyList = <int>[];`.  In general, that's safer than declaring the type with the variable, because if you accidentally omit the generic type parameter (i.e., `List list = [1, 2, 3];`), you'll accidentally be doing `List<dynamic> list = [1, 2, 3];`.

Comment: True that's an alternative, though I don't find that putting the type parameter before the value is inherently any easier to remember than putting it in the type declaration, as the type parameter can be accidentally omitted in either case

Comment: It's true that the type parameter could be omitted in either case, but `var list = [1, 2, 3];` would make `list` a `List<int>` instead of a `List<dynamic>`, and either that's what you want or it is likely to cause a *static* type error.  In contrast, accidentally ending up with a `List<dynamic>` is more likely to be a runtime error or a silent pessimization.  The bottom line is that *incompletely* specifying types is usually worse than specifying *no* types and letting type inference work.